# I want an Ubuntu 12.04 whith Kernel 3.4.6

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I could not find a copy of ubuntu 12.04 Where the kernel ia 3.4.6 . I want to download an Ubuntu 12.04 (kernel 3.4.6). Possible link to download.

Comment: Why do you need kernel 3.4.6?

Comment: for install the RTAI !

Comment: RTAI 5.0 has support for up to kernel 3.18.22.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the `linux-generic-lts-trusty` package on 12.04 will give you the 14.04 kernel, which is 3.13, which should allow you to build RTAI 5.0.